# gradlew command fails in Android Studio terminal

Tags: windows-10, java, android-studio, jdk

I'm trying to run `gradlew` in an Android Studio terminal to setup SonarQube however I get error:

`ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
.0.2\bin`.

`Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.`

I can sucessfully run `java --version` from Windows Command Prompt so I know that I have the Java SDK installed correctly.

I've already tried

- Rebooting
- Removing `\bin` from `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` system variables
- Tried these same things with JDK 12

Comment: What error did you see after removing `/bin` from that path in `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: There is the solution, thank you! Instead of removing `\bin` from both `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` I removed it from only `JAVA_HOME` and the `gradlew` command now works.